# Cocos2D iPhone Effect

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

trying to play around with the Cocos2d effects and created to methods to display and stop the Liquid action. My application however drops from 60fps down to 30fps when the effect is applied  but the fps doesnt increase again when the scheduled stop action is called.

I originally thought that while the action has been completed the effect is still being rendered but after reading through the EffectsTest.h/.m in the Cocos2D 0.8 zip I cant find any reference to how this is achieved. Can anyone shed some light on this issue?

```
// effects
-(void)enableLiquidEffect
{
    id liquid = [Liquid actionWithWaves:6 amplitude:20 grid:ccg(15, 10) duration:3];

    [self schedule:@selector(disableLiquidEffect) interval:(3.0)];

    [self runAction:liquid];
}
-(void)disableLiquidEffect
{
    [self unschedule:@selector(disableLiquidEffect)];
    [self stopAllActions];
}
```

Cheers,
AntonMills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little tip here i know this was asked years ago, but someone might still come here
the code is a little bit overkill, here's how to do it:

```
// effects
-(void)enableLiquidEffect
{
    id liquid = [Liquid actionWithWaves:6 amplitude:20 grid:ccg(15, 10) duration:3];
    //No need to unschedule after 3 seconds since you already set duration-^ to 3 seconds.
    [self runAction:liquid];
}
-(void)disableLiquidEffect
{
    [self stopAllActions];
}
```

besides that the code is perfect

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but since the item will still have a transform set to liquid that it is still trying to apply a more complex transform then needed after its done. Save off your transform prior to starting and then when it stops set it back. You could try just setting it to nil.